# What can I do to reduce temperature using various throttling techniques in 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, temperature

Currently all I'm doing is to use sysfs to force both Cores into Powersave mode, however I'm curious if there are other ways to throttle various parts of the Laptop.

The specification is

Dell Inspiron 640m
Core Duo T5600 (1.83Ghz / 2mb cache)
Centrino (if that gives any indication to the chipset/graphics/etc)
Intel Onboard Graphics
1Gb Memory
250Gb Hitachi HDD (I assume it's 5400rpm since it was low priced, unless all 2.5" drives are 7200rpm now?)

Currently, Ubuntu is allowing me to select 1 / 1.33 / 1.83Ghz profiles for my CPU, can this be dropped lower or are these simply all the CPU provides?

Other steps I'm considering to drop the temperature (please let me know if they are worthwhile) are,

- switching to SSD
- getting a laptop cooling pad

Thanks for any advice :)

EDIT: Just some background info, I want to turn this into a server to run all day/night, and living in HK, ambient temps might get as high as 40C, as I'm not going to leave the air conditioning on while I'm at work.

I left it on overnight, it was about 30C last night I think, and this morning awoke to 50C internal/CPU and 45C HDD, with the lid closed and essentially idle. Opening the lid seems to drop the temp back down to 40-45C all around, so I guess I'll be leaving the lid up.

Answer (score 2):

You could try different things including leaving space behind and under the laptop to let air flow.

You could try also **powertop**, which is a tool for Intel platforms that helps saving Watts. See [LessWatts.org](http://lesswatts.org), i guess it is already included in the repositories.

[image]

Hope it helps